# Matplotlib Scatter Interpolation line

Tags: interpolation, scatter

I have following scatter plot with two dataframes (users and customers).

```
x = [users]
y = [customers]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The scatter plot is working but, how do I find the right way to add an interpolation line between the label points?